# NewtonSoft JsonConvert.SerializeObject adding leading spaces to each property intermittently

Tags: json.net

I am serializing a class using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object)` and sometimes I am observing that *leading spaces* are being inserted to serialized output. I can not reproduce it but it was observed while back.

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object)
```

Output without leading spaces:

```
{"Prop1":1,"Prop2":"Test 1","Prop3":"Test 1.1"}
```

Output with leading spaces:

```
{ "Prop1":1, "Prop2":"Test 1", "Prop3":"Test 1.1"}
```

I know, I can force `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object, Formatting.None)` to avoid any formatting but I am wondering what could be causing this? Any idea?

Comment: anyway this not a problem

Comment: Newtonsoft Json (Json.Net) would not do this out of the box. There are only a few ways I can think of that would produce this output: (1) The JSON was written out manually instead of using a serializer; (2) a custom [JsonTextWriter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter.htm) was used when serializing; or (3) the JSON string was manipulated after serialization. Without a reproducible example, there's not much we can do other than speculate.